# Differentiation of Cross Entropy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, derivative, cross-entropy, differential-equations

I have been trying to create a program for training Neural Networks on my computer. For the Network in question, I have decided to use the Cross Entropy Error function:

$$E = -\sum_jt_j\ln o_j$$

Where $t_j$ is the target output for the Neuron $j$, and $o_j$ is the output of that neuron, attempting to predict $t_j$.

I want to know what $\frac{\delta E}{\delta o_j}$ is for some Neuron $j$. My intuition (plus my limited knowledge of calculus) lead me to believe that this value should be $-\frac{t_j}{o_j}$.

However, this does not seem to be correct. Cross Entropy is often used in tandem with the softmax function, such that $$o_j = \frac{e^{z_j}}{\sum_ke^{z_k}}$$ where z is the set of inputs to all neurons in the softmax layer ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)).

From [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxrtz3auu845fuy/Softmax.pdf?dl=0), I gather that: $$\frac{\delta o_j}{\delta z_j} = o_j(1 - o_j)$$

According to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235528/backpropagation-with-softmax-cross-entropy): $$\frac{\delta E}{\delta z_j} = t_j - o_j$$
But this conflicts with my earlier guess of $\frac{\delta E}{\delta o_j}$. Why?

$$\frac{\delta E_j}{\delta z_j}=\frac{\delta E_j}{\delta o_j}\frac{\delta o_j}{\delta z_j}$$$$\Rightarrow\frac{\delta E_j}{\delta o_j}=\frac{\delta E_j}{\delta z_j}\div\frac{\delta o_j}{\delta z_j}$$
$$= \frac{t_j-o_j}{o_j(1-o_j)}$$ in direct contradiction to my earlier solution of $$-\frac{t_j}{o_j}$$
So which (if either) solution to $\frac{\delta E_j}{\delta o_j}$ is correct, and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your $\frac{\partial E}{\partial o_j}$ is correct, but $\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j}$ should be
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j}=\sum_i\frac{\partial E}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial z_j}$$
when $i=j$, using the results given in the post we have
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial o_j}\frac{\partial o_j}{\partial z_j}=-\frac{t_j}{o_j}o_j(1-o_j)=t_jo_j-t_j$$
when $i\neq j$
$$\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial z_j}=\frac{\partial \frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_ke^{z_k}}}{\partial z_j}=-\frac{e^{z_i}}{(\sum_ke^{z_k})^2}e^{z_j}=-o_io_j$$
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial z_j}=-\frac{t_i}{o_i}(-o_io_j)=t_io_j$$
so the summation is
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j}=\sum_i\frac{\partial E}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial z_j}=\sum_it_io_j-t_j$$
since $t$ is a one-hot vector, $\sum_it_i=1$ therefore
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j}=o_j-t_j$$
also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945871/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function).

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. 
I made the same mistake, because in the case of regression the derivative:
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j}=\sum_i\frac{\partial E}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial z_j}$$
is reduced to:
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial o_j}\frac{\partial o_j}{\partial z_j}$$

But it does not apply in the case of classification.