# Confusion surrounding differentiation of parameter vector ridge regression

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{\beta}$ be the parameter vector of a ridge regression.

Now we can say that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \lambda \beta^T \beta}{\partial \beta}=2\lambda\beta.
\end{equation}

Why is this?

I thought that $$\frac{d}{dx} x^t x = 2x^t$$

Which would imply that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \lambda \beta^T \beta}{\partial \beta}=2\lambda\beta^{T}.
\end{equation}

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257579 and, also, search our site for [matrix cookbook](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+cookbook).  The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234024/question-with-matrix-derivative-why-do-i-have-to-transpose/234071#234071 looks particularly useful concerning the transpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct based on which [layout notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#/Numerator-layout_notation) (i.e. numerator or denominator) is being used. Unfortunately, this is not explicitly stated in most sources and you need to infer it.